# Relational Algebra querying

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

i'm on my exam revision for Relational Algebra queries, where on one of the sample questions I've had quite different approach comparing with the sample question answer. I would really appreciate if someone could give me a tip whether both of them are valid? if not what's wrong with my approach, thanks.

**From the following entities:**

DEPARTMENT (*dept-name, staff-size, location)

DEPARTMENT-STAFF (*dept-name, *staff-no)

STAFF (*staff-no, staff-name, salary-grade, salary)

**I was asked to:** 
Find the names of employees who work in the FOREIGN EXCHANGE and the INSURANCE departments.

**My approach:**

```
    RESTRICT Department-Staff WHERE dept-name = 'Foreign Exchange' GIVING T1

     RESTRICT Department-Staff WHERE dept-name = 'Insurance' GIVING T2

        T1 intersect T2 giving T3

         JOIN T3 and Staff (OVER Staff-no) giving T4

           PROJECT T4 over Staff-name giving RESULT
```

**Meanwhile at the sample question answer:**

```
RESTRICT DEPARTMENT-STAFF where DEPT-NAME = 'FOREIGN EXCHANGE' giving T1

RESTRICT DEPARTMENT-STAFF where DEPT-NAME = 'INSURANCE' giving T2

JOIN T1 and STAFF (over STAFF-NO) giving T3 

JOIN T2 and STAFF (over STAFF-NO) giving T4

T3 INTERSECT T4 GIVING T5

PROJECT T5 over STAFF-NAME GIVING RESULT
```

Answer (score 0):

Your T1 INTERSECT T2 giving T3 is wrong.  How could that intersection ever contain anything ?

The model answer is wrong for the same reason, BTW, at the place where it does T3 INTERSECT T4 GIVING T5.